# Poisson Process, infinite servers: Waiting time distribution and expected waiting

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-process

Buses arrive at a restaurant as a Poisson process with rate $\alpha$. Each bus contains a random number of hungry customers constituting iid non-negative integer valued random variables. The restaurant has infinite servers. Each customer spends a random amount of time ordering and waiting for his food such that the waiting times are iid and independent of other random variables.

Let $X(t)$ be the number of customers whp arrived in $[0,t]$ and are still waiting for food at time $t$.

1. Find $E(X(t))$
2. What is the distribution of $X(t)$?

If the random number of hungry customers in each bus was not mentioned, I would have proceeded using thinning with $X(t)$ being a Poisson process with mean measure
$$\lambda\int_0^t(1-G(t-s))ds$$ where, the waiting times have the common distribution $G$. However, with this new random variable introduced, I can't figure how to proceed. Each bus has a certain probability of containing some customers, does that mean a factor will be introduced in the above integraln somewhere? Where and how?

For part(2), I need compound processes but a little hint would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the expected value of $X(t)$, we can use the fact that $X(t)$ is a counting process, which means that it can be written as a sum of independent indicator random variables.

In this case, each customer arriving at the restaurant corresponds to an indicator random variable that is 1 if the customer is still waiting for food at time $t$ and 0 otherwise. Therefore, we can write:

$$X(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} I_i$$

where $N(t)$ is the number of customers who have arrived at the restaurant by time $t$ and $I_i$ is an indicator random variable for the $i$th customer.

Since the number of customers arriving at the restaurant follows a Poisson process with rate $\alpha$, the expected value of $N(t)$ is $\alpha t$. Furthermore, the expected value of each indicator random variable $I_i$ is $1-G(t)$, where $G(t)$ is the distribution function of the waiting times.

Therefore, we can compute the expected value of $X(t)$ as:

$$E(X(t)) = \sum_{i=1}^{\alpha t} E(I_i) = \alpha t (1-G(t))$$

For the distribution of $X(t)$, we can use the fact that $X(t)$ is a compound Poisson process. This means that it can be written as the sum of independent and identically distributed random variables, where the number of random variables is itself a Poisson random variable.

In this case, the random variables are the indicator random variables $I_i$ and the Poisson random variable is $N(t)$. Therefore, the distribution of $X(t)$ is given by:

$$P(X(t) = k) = \sum_{n=k}^\infty P(N(t) = n)P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n I_i = k\right)$$

where $P(N(t) = n)$ is the probability mass function of a Poisson random variable with mean $\alpha t$ and $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n I_i = k\right)$ is the probability mass function of a sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with success probability $1-G(t)$.

To compute this distribution explicitly, you can use the probability mass function of the Poisson distribution and the binomial distribution.

Comment: Hello, for the expectation how did you make appear the $\alpha t$ in the sum ? I have never seen a random variable as the upper limit of summation so I am a little bit curious aha.

Comment: In the problem you mentioned, the random variable $N(t)$ represents the number of customers who have arrived at the restaurant by time $t$. Since the arrival times of the customers follow a Poisson process with rate $\alpha$, the expected value of $N(t)$ is $\alpha t$.

Therefore, the expected value of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} I_i$ is $\alpha t (1-G(t))$, where $G(t)$ is the distribution function of the waiting times.

This is just a property of the Poisson process. Specifically, if $N(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, then its expected value is $\lambda t$.

Comment: @MarcoDJ01 I understand your solution, but is the information that each bus contains a random number of customers constituting  iid non negative random variables unnecessary? I don't think it has been used in your solution anywherer.

Comment: Also, the issue mentioned by @coboy is smth I am having trouble with. The property is that the mean value is $\alpha t$. But how could you get the expected value when there is a whole random variable on the summand? I believe in such a case $E X(t)$ is $\lambda\int_0^t(1-G(s))ds$